# How to scroll gridview to position?

Tags: android

I have 30 images on grid view (3 images per row). If user select 20th image and go to next screen and come back then I want to focus to that position. I used following line to code, it works for first 8 rows but in last 2 row it is not scrolling. Please help.

```
gridview.setSelection(position);
gridview.requestFocusFromTouch();
gridview.setSelection(position);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason is because your view will be reused in your adapter.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] someprivatevariable;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
        // Your boring constructor
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

            // REUSE VIEW IF NOT NULL CODE
        if (convertView == null) {
                  .....
                  .....
                  you generally create your view here
        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }
}
```

If your view is forced not to reuse then you can scrolltoposition by saving this value

```
int index = gridview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

and restore the value by

```
gridview.smoothScrollToPosition(int index)
```

Comment: @lalitab B but smoothScrollToPosition(index) is not working for ICS.Is there any way to use on ICS Please tell me thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Lalith B Do you know how to make a NOT smooth scroll? I have >1000 elements in my grid view and smoothScroll takes a while.

Answer (score 7):

You can try somthing like this .I hope this will work for you..

When selection happens do this save position

```
int index = gridview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

And when you come back to the gridview then you can try this

```
gridview.smoothScrollToPosition(int index)
```

Answer (score 1):

solution that worked for me was combine code from Monali and Sreedev (thank  you Monali and Sreedev):

```
private int gridviewVerticalPositionWhenThumbnailTapped;
```

...

```
// save vertical position of gridview screen, will use to re-find this location if user follows a usre and gridview gets redrawn
gridviewVerticalPositionWhenThumbnailTapped = gridview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

later in app...

```
// scroll gridview to vertical position pre user tap follow                
gridview.setSelection(gridviewVerticalPositionWhenThumbnailTapped);
```