# Is it possible set the scroll of a gridview at the end of it contextually an item is added?

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

Is it possible set the scroll of a GridView at the end of it contextually an item is added?

Comment: Maybe this one is : [How to scroll gridview][1] what you need.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757325/how-to-scroll-gridview-to-position

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this as a parent to your xml layout file.

```html
<ScrollView>
  
  </ScrollView>
```