# How to maintain Android GridView position in all cases?

Tags: android, gridview

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to do the following task on my school project:

I have a grid view of movies which the user can scroll endlessly.
When the app starts I fetch the first 20 movies and each time the user scrolls to the bottom of the grid I execute an AsyncTask to fetch 20 more movies and add them to the Adapter.

When the user clicks on a movie he goes to a new child activity to see the movie details.

I'm having troubles maintaining the GridView's scroll position in the following cases:

1. When the user goes to the details activity and returns to the main activity of the movies.
2. When the user changes the device orientation.

And when dealing with theses 2 cases I also need to take in consideration that maybe the user scrolled a lot and had 100 movies in the adapter and when he goes back the activity start from the start with only the first 20 movies, so I would be able to scroll to his last position.

Can someone please tell me how can I give the best user experience in my project by not losing the user's scroll position at any case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best practice, but in my case it is.
I decided to set my adapter as a global static variable, in this way I maintain the amount of data loaded via the API, and I don't need to perform a request for every time the user moves between activities.
For maintaining the scroll position I used the `onItemClickListener` when moving to the details activity and the `savedInstanceState` when changing orientation.

Here is my code for that:

```
//Static variables
private static MoviesAdapter mMoviesAdapter;
private static int mGridViewPosition = 0;

//Call this method when user clicks the back button
public static void ClearStaticData(){
    mMoviesAdapter.clear();
    mMoviesAdapter = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    int index = mGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    outState.putInt(GRID_VIEW_POSITION, index);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(...) {
    if (mMoviesAdapter == null) {
        mMoviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(...);
    } else {
        RestoreGridPosition();
    }
}

private void RestoreGridPosition(){
    if(mGridViewPosition > 0 && mMoviesAdapter.getCount() >= mGridViewPosition)
        mGridView.setSelection(mGridViewPosition);
}
```

Since I fill my adapter via API call, I think this is probably the best solution to save the data and not to perform requests every time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try not finishing `mainActivity` once a `gridItem` is clicked so when user navigates back to `mainActivity` (from `detailsActivity`) he will have all the data that was there before.
2. You can handle this situation with activity's lifecycle callbacks:

You can get currently visible GridView item's position like this:

```
int mCurrentPosition = gridview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

When an orientation change is occurring the activity is recreated and going through the following stages:

onSaveInstanceState 
onRestoreInstanceState

You can then save the position before orientation change is happening and get it back when its being restored.

**Save Your Activity State**

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Save the user's current scroll state
savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);

// Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**Restore Your Activity State**

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore state members from saved instance
    mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POSITION);
}
```

Here once you have the previous position you can move to the desired position in the gridView:

```
gridview.smoothScrollToPosition(int mCurrentPosition)
```

This is taken from android docs: [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState) 
Scrolling gridView to position [GridView scrolling stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757325/how-to-scroll-gridview-to-position)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. can you please tell me how do I

1. "not finishing mainActivity once a gridItem is clicked"?

2. The `gridview.getFirstVisiblePosition();` sometimes brings the position of a half scrolled item, and it doesn't work so well...

Comment: Since I'm using a fragment, I don't seem to have the `onRestoreInstanceState` event.

Comment: You're right. Check the following [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412746/android-fragment-onrestoreinstancestate)

Comment: You're right. Check the following [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412746/android-fragment-onrestoreinstancestate). About not finishing the activity - if you start `DetailsActivity` without calling `MainActivity.finish()` than it should be in the back-stack and when user navigates back he should be returned to the previous state.